# Aligning BIRT charts regardless of the legend size

Tags: charts, birt

I have created a BIRT report with multiple charts.
All the charts include different data but for the same time span.
So i want to make the x axis of the charts align with each other so it is easy to read all the charts at once.

But the series names of these charts are different from each other.And some charts gets dynamic series names in which the length cannot be predicted.

Even though i align the charts with same width and height because of the series names the legend gets too lengthy and the alignment gets ruined.

According to the requirements given to me legend should be placed at the right side of the chart.

Is there a way to fix the size of the legend without truncating the series names.May be a way to wrap the series names so the size of the legend will be same for all the charts and the charts will be aligned nicely.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your Eclipse designer:

*Edit charts -> Format charts -> Legend -> Layout -> Wrapping width*

Set a wrapping width value as expected, for example try 60.

You might also have to increase the bottom inset of legend entries to avoid overlapping:

*Edit charts -> Format charts -> Legend -> Entries -> Bottom inset*

Comment: Thank you. It did solve the problem of wrapping the series title. But for some reason it didn't solve my initial problem of aligning the charts http://i60.tinypic.com/29yqlw6.png

Answer (score 0):

From your Eclipse designer: set Format Chart->Legend->Entries->Ellipsis property to possible max length of your dynamic legends. and the problem will be solved.

As this property work as follows:
The default value is "1". Int attribute "Ellipsis" specifies the behavior of shortening the legend item's text with ellipsis if there is not enough space to display the whole text. Value 0 indicates that the feature is disabled, and the legend item will either be displayed with whole text or be dropped. A positive value n represents the minimal count of characters to be displayed before the ellipsis, which means the legend item will either be dropped or be displayed with at least n characters.

Hope this will solve your problem. It worked for me.